# Rename column, but ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: unknown column: 'shop_address_lookup'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Using Rails 4, Thinking Sphinx 3.2.0. I recently renamed a column from `for_search` to `address_lookup`. The `Shop` model has the column `address_lookup`, and I have `Country` which is associated to `Shop` model.

Here's my `Country` index:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :state, with: :real_time do
  indexes name
  indexes shop_address_lookup
  ...
end
```

I removed the `development.sphinx.conf`, and ran `ts:regenerate`. Indexing `Shop` worked fine, but when it tried to index `Country`, it kept throwing the following error:

```
Generating index files for country_core
rake aborted!
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: unknown column: 'shop_address_lookup' - REPLACE INTO country_core (id, `sphinx_internal_class_name`, `name`, `country_status`, `shop_address_lookup`
...
/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Innertube::Pool::BadResource: Innertube::Pool::BadResource
/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
ThinkingSphinx::QueryExecutionError: unknown column: 'shop_address_lookup'
...
/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: unknown column: 'shop_address_lookup'
/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => ts:regenerate => ts:generate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I only renamed the column, and already updated my index file. What can I do to fix this?

Note: When I rename the index from `shop_address_lookup` to `shop_for_search` again, without changing the actual column name, the index works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work finally - remove `db/sphinx/development/*` before running `rake ts:regenerate`.

Note to self:

```
abc@Vmac-2 ~/Sites/xyz (master●●)$ rake ts:regenerate
Stopped searchd daemon (pid: 65211).
Generating configuration to /Users/abc/Sites/xyz/config/development.sphinx.conf
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /Users/abc/Sites/xyz/log/development.searchd.log.
Failed to start searchd. Check the log files for more information.
Generating index files for spot_core
^C%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     abc@Vmac-2 ~/Sites/xyz (master●●)$ ps aux | grep searcd
abc      65649   0.0  0.0  2423380    300 s001  R+    2:10AM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto searcd
abc@Vmac-2 ~/Sites/xyz (master●●)$ ps aux | grep searchd
abc      65727   0.0  0.0  2435864    788 s001  R+    2:10AM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto searchd
========== REMOVE db/sphinx/development/* at this step ============
abc@Vmac-2 ~/Sites/xyz (master●●)$ rake ts:regenerate
searchd is not currently running.
Stopped searchd daemon (pid: ).
Generating configuration to /Users/abc/Sites/xyz/config/development.sphinx.conf
Started searchd successfully (pid: 65936).
Generating index files for shop_core
..........................
Generating index files for trip_core
........
```